# Is there a good word that means "dishonest charges" or "dishonest fees"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the right term for when a company charges you for something, knowing full well that they are not giving you what you are paying for.

Some background: My power company is charging me for something on my bill, and then on the same bill saying that they did NOT provide that thing. I've called them to get the charge removed but it is never taken care of. Of course, it's not quite so simple as they feel they have a right to charge me for it, but from my perspective, it's sort of fraud-like.

I'm trying to make my case in a written letter and I want to be able to say it with some impact, and I think the proper word will be useful here.

Terms that seem close but don't quite get it would be "fraud" and "unjust enrichment". I can't quite say "fraud" because technically, they are not deceiving me at all, as they are admitting that they are not providing the thing they are charging for.

There must be some good legal term that nails it.

EDIT: Perhaps "unjust enrichment" is correct. Here is the definition from Black's 8th Edition:

> UNJUST ENRICHMENT  unjust enrichment. 1. The retention of a benefit
> conferred by another, without offering  compensation, in circumstances
> where compensation is reasonably expected. [Cases: Implied and
> Constructive Contracts 3. C.J.S. Implied and Constructive Contracts §
> 5.] 2. A benefit obtained  from another, not intended as a gift and not legally justifiable, for which the beneficiary must make
> restitution or recompense. 3. The area of law dealing with
> unjustifiable benefits of this kind.

That accurately defines what I am saying they are doing. Compensation could reasonably be expected, but they are not offering the compensation required to receive the payment. It was not intended as a gift and is not legally justifiable. They are charging unwarranted, undue, unjustified fees leading to unjust enrichment.

I'm still unsure so I can't yet say this is the correct answer.

Comment: Calling a charge incorrect is more effective than labeling it ridiculous, egregious or anything. Otherwise, your letter responds to *You're a baby* with *I'm not a baby*. Just saying. Ah, @Lambie has it.

Comment: That is called: overbilling or an overbilled item or overcharging.

Comment: It's sadly humorous that your power company is gaslighting you.

Comment: dishonest charges (as in illegal)  sounds like something a lawyer might say. It is not a term, per se.

Comment: If something to the effect of 'please correct your mistake' followed by the arithmetic doesn't work, can you Post the exact words charging you and saying that they did NOT provide that thing?

Comment: As a happy ending to the story, I reported them to PUCO (public utility commission of Ohio) and they went to bat for me. I ended up getting nearly $500 returned to me. I don't think my letter to them did anything, but notifying PUCO did. I referred to the fees as both erroneous and unjustified.

Comment: My power company had to replace a pole on the other side of the street. A new pole was left on my side of the street on the grass between the sidewalk and the curb. When the boom truck arrived next day, they had to lop some large limbs off my tree, which were overhanging the "verge" on my side of the street, nowhere near their wires, in order to swing the pole into position. And they left the limbs on my front yard for me to deal with at my expense. Minimum "site visit" charges from tree companies in my area are $350. The power co says it's not their "policy" to remove tree limbs they've cut.

Comment: Maybe I'll try the public utility commission here

Comment: @TimR  You can also check your town/city's local ordinances.

Comment: A legal term such as *unjust enrichment* gets its full meaning from a large body of the law in which it is used. A brief entry in a legal dictionary cannot be expected to be anything more than a very rough summary of that large body of the law, and is therefore likely to be of limited use if one wants to learn how to use the term; to do that one has to actually acquaint oneself with the relevant law itself. Note also, that, even in the everyday sense of *enrichment*, nobody got enriched here: the company has not received the money, it is merely asking for it.

Answer (score -1):

A term that conveys the idea you want to express is:

Undue:

> not due : not yet payable.

(M-W)

Comment: The fees are undue, but what is it when the company is billing you for those undue fees?

Comment: @Benthink that depends on the reason why the overcharged you. Whatever the case the amount of charges is undue. That’s the point.

Comment: You've quoted the wrong definition of *undue*.

Comment: Per @TinfoilHat, you must want #2: "Excessive," rather than the *not yet due* definition.

Comment: Note that "undue charge" usually implies there's some value, but not as much as they charged. It seems wrong to use it when they charge for nothing.

Comment: @Barmar - undue is for something that is not due either because you didn’t receive  it or because of lower quality, standard etc,

Answer (score -1):

The charges are at least *nugatory*. The word attributes a value of nothing to the charges, and at first sight does not capture the sense of dishonesty that you ask for. But a charge for a service that is stated as not provided is not really *dishonest*, so I suggest that nugatory is - on reflection - appropriate.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nugatory)
> *nugatory*, adjective   formal:
> worth nothing or of little value:

Comment: Nugatory would apply to a service that you don't think is worth paying for. I don't see how it applies to the charge itself.